# How to add new records in a table with temp values in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a table with records. There is an option for inline editing when you click on the field. There is an option to add new rows.

The problem is that when I click Add New 2 times and there are 2 empty rows in the table with inputs and start typing, field values for both rows are changed.

It's because I use `v-model="temp.name"` and `isCreateMode` and in my case there are several rows with this `temp` model, but I'm not sure how to deal with this.

`temp` is necessary because users can cancel editing the field. I use the same input fields for create and edit.

```js
//in component
// other code here
computed: {
  ...mapState([
    'editModeField',
    'editedUser',
    'editMode',
    'createMode',
    'temp',
    'users'
  ]),
  ...mapGetters([
    'filteredUsers'
  ]),
  isEditable (field, user, index) {
    if (this.isCreateMode(user)) {
      return this.users[index] === user
    }
    return this.editedUser === user && this.editModeField === 
    field
  },
   isEditMode (field, user) {
     return this.editMode && this.editedUser === user && 
      this.editModeField === field
  },
  isCreateMode (user) {
    return this.createMode && !user.id
  },
  addUser (user, index) {
    if (!user) {
      user = {
        name: '',       
        car: ''
      }
      this.toggleCreateMode(true)
      this.createUser(user)
      return
    }
    // this makes a request to the endpoint 
    this.storeUser(user, index)
  },
  
  
  //actions.js
  createUser ({ state, commit }, user) {
    commit('CREATE_USER', user)
    commit('SET_TEMP_OBJECT', { name: '', car: null })
  },
  
  //mutations
   CREATE_USER (state, user) {
    state.users.push(user)
  },
  SET_TEMP_OBJECT (state, user) {
    state.temp = user
  },
```

```html
<table>
<tr v-for="user, index in filteredUsers">
  <td>{{ index + 1 }}</td>
  <td>
    <input
      v-if="isEditable('name', user, index)"
      v-model="temp.name"
      v-focus="!isCreateMode(user)" />
    <div v-if="isEditMode('name', user)"
       @click="updateField('name', user)"></div>
    <span v-if="isEditMode('name', user)"
      @click="cancelUpdate('name', user)"></span>
    <span
      v-if="isShowMode('name', user)"
      @click="editField('name', user)">{{ user.name }}</span>
  </td>
   <td>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)"
      @click="addUser()">
      Add user</a>
  </td>
  // other columns
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about preventing the user from adding a new input unless he submits the existing one:

i can't really see how your code works since you didn't provide the `temp` / state of your store data but the suggested solution should be something like this :

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    users: ['foo', 'bar'],
    input: '',
    counter: 0
  },
  methods: {
    addUser(user) {
      if (this.counter == 0) {
        this.counter++
      } else if (this.counter == 1 && user) {
        this.counter--
          this.input = ''
        this.users.push(user)
      } else {
        alert('please fill the exisiting input')
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-for="n in counter" type="text" v-model="input">
  <button @click="addUser(input)">addUser</button>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="user in users">{{user}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a workaround. I am trying to do that without such a validation. I'm not sure if it is possible though. It seems complex

Comment: @mistery_girl i can implement that on your code if you provided full code or a fork for a demo/live template example

Comment: @mistery_girl there is another way which passes the input text (value) immediately to the method via the event without the need of using `v-model` ...with this you can handle as much inputs

Comment: Yes, I've tried this approach, but the thing is that the logic is complex and this broke the edit functionality. I really appreciate that but the repo is private and cannot share it. I will try to debug it, thanks.